Renaming columns in R 4.3 using native pipe
I have a sequence of operations that I use the R 4.3 pipe to execute:
df <- alfred::get_alfred_series(CHAUVET_PIGER_PROB)
unrevised_df <- df |>
                    within(Delta <- realtime_period - date) |>
                    na.omit() |>
                    subset(Delta == ave(Delta, date, FUN = min)) |>
                    subset(Delta <60) |>
                    within(date <- zoo::as.yearmon(format(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))) |>
                    subset(select = -c(Delta, realtime_period))


> head(unrevised_df)
           date UNRATE
146  1960-02-01    4.8
1065 1960-03-01    5.4
1984 1960-04-01    5.0
2903 1960-05-01    4.9
3822 1960-06-01    5.5
4741 1960-07-01    5.4

I would like to add one more line to my sequence to change the name of the first column from date to Date without having to invoke dplyr. I'm aware that I can simply add a separate line that reads
colnames(unrevised_df[1]) <- "Date"
but I would like to make this a line in the pipe. How can I do this?
Your help is greatly appreciated.
Sincerely
Thomas Philips

Stupid question but why rename it, when you could name it correctly right away within(Date <- zoo::as.yearmon(format(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')))?

Here are a few other approaches.  The first uses an anonymous function and the others use the trick of boxing the input into a list.
# 1
unrevised_df |>
  (\(x) { names(x)[1] <- "Date"; x })()

# 2
unrevised_df |>
  list(x = _) |>
  with( { names(x)[1] <- "Date"; x } )

# 3
unrevised_df |>
  list(x = _) |>
  with( setNames(x, replace(names(x), 1, "Date")) )

# 4
unrevised_df |>
  list(x = _) |>
  with(cbind(Date = x[[1]], x[-1]))

If you are willing to use magrittr (which is very stable and does not involve using dplyr, tidyr or any other tidyverse package) we can do this:
# 5
library(magrittr)
unrevised_df %>%
  { names(.)[1] <- "Date"; . } 

The Bizarro pipe is not really a pipe but just base R syntax that looks like one:
# 6
unrevised_df ->.;
  { names(.)[1] <- "Date"; . } 

Another possibility is to define your own pipe.  This pipe does not do automatic substitution but instead requires that dot (.) on the right hand side be used. It is only one additional line of code to define it keeping the code independent of any packages.
"%.>%" <- function(left, right) eval(substitute(right), list(. = left))

unrevised_df %.>%
  { names(.)[1] <- "Date"; . } 

Note
The input in reproducible form
unrevised_df <- data.frame(
  date = c("1960-02-01", "1960-03-01", "1960-04-01", "1960-05-01", "1960-06-01", "1960-07-01"),
  UNRATE = c(4.8, 5.4, 5, 4.9, 5.5, 5.4),
  row.names = c("146", "1065", "1984", "2903", "3822", "4741")
)


I would up using unrevised_df  |>  ``colnames<-``(c("Date", new_name)), where newname is passed as a parameter into the function but I'll try #1 and #5 as well.  (Only a single backtick around colnames). Thanks as always.

@Thomas, I think you meant unrevised_df |> \colnames<-`(c("Date", "UNRATE"))` but I thoughht the idea of the question is to avoid having to replace all the names.  (In comments to SO you can use backslash to protect backticks.)

Added alternative (7).

Although it appears odd to me to write Date = date, date = NULL, using transform() is easy-to-read and straightforward:
1)
> df |> 
+   transform(Date = date, date = NULL)
     UNRATE       Date
146     4.8 1960-02-01
1065    5.4 1960-03-01
1984    5.0 1960-04-01
2903    4.9 1960-05-01
3822    5.5 1960-06-01
4741    5.4 1960-07-01

2) Hard-coded using colnames()
df |> 
  `colnames<-`(c("Date", "Unrate"))

3) A small wrapper
rename = \(df, pos, nm) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
  names(df)[pos] = nm
  df
}

df |>
  rename(df=_, 1L, "Date")

4) For more than one name
rename2 = \(df, new, old) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df), length(old) == length(new), is.character(new))
  # this check needs to be revised:
  if(! inherits(old, c("numeric", "character", "integer"))) 
    stop("Specify 'old' either as character or integer/numeric.") 
  if(is.character(old)) 
    if(all(sapply(old, \(x) x %in% names(df))==FALSE)) 
      stop("Names in 'old' do not match with names of df.") else 
        names(df)[match(old, names(df))] = new 
      else names(df)[old] = new 
  df
}

mtcars |>
  rename2(c("lala", "blabla"), c("am", "disp"))

mtcars |>
  rename2(c("lala", "blabla"), 7:8)


Data
df = read.table(text ="          date UNRATE
146  1960-02-01    4.8
1065 1960-03-01    5.4
1984 1960-04-01    5.0
2903 1960-05-01    4.9
3822 1960-06-01    5.5
4741 1960-07-01    5.4", header = TRUE)


df |>    colnames<-(c("Date", "Unrate")) is remarkably simple, but I don't seem to be able to modify only the first name (the second will vary depending on what is being downloaded. I tried df |>    colnames[1]<- ("Date") but got nowhere. I'd like to keep Date as the first column if I can

Use the wrapper.

OK. I was hoping that R would have a built-in function similar to rename

@ThomasPhilips there are certainly drawbacks to the tidyverse - as you mentioned in your other question, the API changes frequently. One reason for that is because a lot of thought goes into how to create functions that are consistent and user-friendly. If you want to trade the tidyverse for base R to gain stability, you're going to sacrifice some convenience.

Also @Friede when you say your first approach is not efficient, do you mean in terms of typing? It doesn't copy the data.

@SamR, yeah, it appears annoying to me to type Date = date, date = NULL. Thank you, I have clarified it.

@SamR Good point, and it's a trade I'm willing to make. I'm not a particularly good programmer (count me as one of the people who put the Overflow into StackOverflow), so once I get something sorted out, I'd like it to stay that way. I tried the tidyverse a few years ago, and was surprised by how often stuff changed. A friend then told me that he had had the same experience, and advised me to stick with base R as far as possible, and to use a carefully curated packages when required.
